# "He called me to repair the computer" or "for repairing the computer"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Could you please tell me which are grammatically correct

Whether To+verb or for+ verb+ing?

> He called me to repair the computer or ... for repairing the computer"

> "I am here to repair the computer or ... for repairing the computer"

> "He invited me to repair the computer or ... for repairing the computer"

Comment: There are several questions on these constructions.  There is no doubt that "to repair" is the only idiomatic form in each case. The "for repairing" form is borderline ungrammatical. The reason is complex, but the linked duplicate has a longish discussion.

Comment: The only one that makes much sense to me is "I am here to repair the computer".  I'm not quite sure what you mean by the others, so I'd avoid all of them. Sorry.  Can you explain the situation or context more, then it might be easier to help you. Thanks.

Comment: @James K thank you for the link. It was useful. Can you also tell me what is meant by birderkine ungrammatical pls.

Answer (score 1):

Correct: He called me **to** repair the computer. I am here **to** repair the computer. He invited me **to** repair the computer. (NOT *for repairing*)

We don't use '*for*' before a *verb* to talk about purpose. Instead, we use **to** + infinitive.

She went to Canada **to** attend the conference. He is studying everyday **to** improve his English. I am going to New York **to** visit my grandmother. I went there **to** buy a watch.

[[ We can use **for** before a **noun** to talk about a **purpose**.

I went to Paris **for** an interview. He went to the pub **for** a drink. He is studying hard **for** the exam.

We can use  before a verb to talk about the **purpose of a thing**. (the reason **why we use it**)

We use an altimeter  measur height above sea level. That stuff is (used)  clean leather. The garden shears are used  clip the hedge. He wears these old trousers  paint.]]

Comment: But we *do* use "for" to talk about purpose: "*Wallets are **for** holding money and credit cards*". This means **the purpose** of a wallet is holding money and credit cards. Please explain how *[ "for" + gerund ]* differs from *[ "to" + base form ]* in terms of talking about purpose

Comment: We can use  to talk about the purpose of  a thing. (the reason why we use it) ''Wallets are  hold money and credit cards.'' We use an altimeter  measur height above sea level. That stuff is (used)  clean leather. The garden shears are used  clip the hedge. He wears these old trousers  paint.